# MySQL: выборка по условию, в котором используется поле datetime

Tags: mysql

Нужно вытащить из таблицы новости по полю created (дата создания). Тип поля - datetime.

```
$date = '2014-01-01 15:00:00';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE created > " . $date;
```

Когда выполняю этот запрос, выдается ошибка... типа неверный синтаксис:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Как преобразовать дату в datetime? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = '2014-01-01 15:00:00';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE created > '" . $date . "'";
```

Оберните дату в кавычки, что бы она воспринималась как строка.